# Android Game UI advice

Tags: android

I want to start making a game for Android and I'm looking for a good resource to use to make the ui, I want to make a game like EzpzRPG or monster warlord I want the ui to be similar, any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest this [for game development.](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) But then again do you have experience with Android or Java itself?

Learning about Android API is the first step.

Comment: I do have experience, I just want to know if there's anything better than the XML editor that comes with eclipse

Comment: XML is part of Android. As far as I know there is no workaround to it. However I would suggest using Android Studio over Eclipse.